# How to convert varchar dates into datetime2 dates

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I have uploaded my table into SQL Server with every column as either `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` datatype. The reason I did this was because I was uploading from a `.CSV` file that had millions of records and I didn't want to spend hours cleaning up the data before entering it into SQL Server.

However, I now have all types of characters in my `Log_Date` column. I am able to identify the two formatted log_dates that I want.

The two log date formats are

1. `MM/DD/YYYY MM:SS` (or **M**/**D**/YYYY **M**:SS) or
2. are in an appropriate datetime format

I can't convert the `Log_Date` to `datetime` characters since there are other datatypes in there (words, symbols, numbers & symbols, etc) that prevent a conversion.

How can I convert my `varchar Log_Date` of `MM/DD/YYYY MM:SS` (or **M**/**D**/YYYY **M**:SS) to just `datetime`?

This is what I tried but it doesn't convert the records.

```
select 
     id
    ,log_date
    ,case when log_date like '%[0-9]%/%[0-9]%/%[0-9]%' 
         then try_convert(datetime2,log_date,126) 
         else null 
     end as Potato
from 
    full_union
where 
    id not like '%[^0-9]%'
    and id = 4112541
```

See below for an excerpt of my results

```
id      log_date                        Potato
-----------------------------------------------
4112541 2/13/2019 15:41                 NULL
4112541 2/13/2019 15:41                 NULL
4112541 2019-04-18 11:42:00.0000000     NULL
4112541 2019-04-18 11:45:00.0000000     NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format 126 is very specifically the ISO standard format, with a "T" between the date and the time.

SQL Server is pretty good about figuring out formats, so this might be sufficient:

```
(case when log_date like '%[0-9]%-%[0-9]%-%[0-9]%' 
     then try_convert(datetime2, log_date) 
 end) as Potato
```

EDIT:

You have a problem because of the `/` in your pattern.  But even with that fixed, it is not working.  Something strange is going on with the hyphens.  This does work:

```
(case when log_date like '%[0-9]%_%[0-9]%_%[0-9]%' 
     then try_convert(datetime2,log_date) 
     else '2000-01-01' 
 end) as Potato
```

Comment: I tried that but it still returns null.  Not sure why convert isn't working.  Casting works:  cast(log_date as datetime2).  Try this fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2b3af/6

Comment: Thank you KingOfAllTrades! So far this works for my current id. I'll try the rest of my logs soon!

Comment: Does anyone know how I can give KingOfAllTrades credit for answering my question?

Comment: @Computer_Nerd . . . You can accept this answer or upvote it.  Anyone (with enough reputation) can upvote an answer.  Only the OP can accept it -- and only one answer per question can be accepted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My question was answered by someone who clicked on "Add Comment" instead of "Post Your Answer". I was looking for a way to give credit to the person who answered my question through a comment.